How to keep API alive, or how to check if it is online (status 200)?
I'm struggling with a problem that I haven't found a good solution for yet.
I have an API that I would like to monitor at appropriate intervals to see if it returns 200, e.g. every 1 minute, in the case of 4xx / 5xx it starts a function that triggers a notification with the content of the alarm on the phone.

The solution would be another API that sends requests from time to time, however:
It is the same infrastructure as the monitored API,
each API in this system is put to sleep after 30 minutes of inactivity (no requests to them).

Another option that comes to my mind is a widget / application on the phone running in the background, which sends requests to the above API, but I have never written anything for Android in my life and I would like a solution right away.

The last thing I came up with is a console / desktop application running in the background, which performs the above activities.



We aren't really a programming service here. We also don't really do "solution recommendations". Present a narrow, specific problem, with sufficient information that we can provide a concrete and confident answer, and we'll do what we can to help you get that answer. For this: Pick a solution and begin working towards it. As you come upon problems you are unable to solve while doing that work, we might be able to help with that.
